# Ansible stat module not working

Tags: ansible

I need some help here:

I am creating virtual machines with Vagrant to configure some cluster on them. For the first VM, which I want to use as an Ansible control node, I'm running Ansible from my local machine to install and configure Ansible in my  Control Node.

The problem appears when I try to check if the `.inventory` file exists and try to copy the file to the home directory (inside the VM).

The same command that I use for the inventory file works just file to check the stat of the .ansible.cfg file but not for the inventory file.

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

`roles/ansible/tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: install epel-release
  yum:
    name: epel-release
    state: present

- name: install ansible
  yum:
    name: ansible
    state: present

- name: stat ansible configuration file
  stat:
    path: "{{ cfg_file }}"
  register: stat_ansible_config

- name: copy .ansible.cfg to home directory
  copy:
    src: .ansible.cfg
    dest: /home/{{ user }}/.ansible.cfg
    owner: "{{ user }}"
    group: "{{ group }}"
    mode: 0644
  when: stat_ansible_config.stat.exists

- name: stat ansible inventory file
  stat:
    path: "{{ inventory_file }}"
  register: stat_inventory

- name: copy .inventory to home directory
  copy:
    src: .inventory
    dest: /home/{{ user }}/.inventory
    owner: "{{ user }}"
    group: "{{ group }}"
    mode: 0644
  when: stat_inventory.stat.exists
...
```

`roles/ansible/vars/main.yml`

```
---
user: vagrant
group: vagrant
cfg_file:       /{{ user }}/provision/playbooks/roles/ansible/files/.ansible.cfg
inventory_file: /{{ user }}/provision/playbooks/roles/ansible/files/.inventory
...
```

`the playbook:`

```
---
- hosts: controller
  become: yes

  roles:
    - ansible
...
```

`and the output:`

```
TASK [ansible : stat ansible configuration file] *******************************

ok: [controller] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
            "follow": false,
            "get_checksum": true,
            "get_md5": true,
            "mime": false,
            "path": "/vagrant/provision/playbooks/roles/ansible/files/.ansible.cfg"
        },
        "module_name": "stat"
    },
    "stat": {
        "atime": 1485527858.0,
        "checksum": "46acc076fda7e38fd7262fbc88f8ab4e1f52ddca",
        "ctime": 1485452789.0,
        "dev": 38,
        "executable": false,
        "exists": true,
        "gid": 1000,
        "gr_name": "vagrant",
        "inode": 118,
        "isblk": false,
        "ischr": false,
        "isdir": false,
        "isfifo": false,
        "isgid": false,
        "islnk": false,
        "isreg": true,
        "issock": false,
        "isuid": false,
        "md5": "0cb8c97246776dc7e88fe44f19c3278f",
        "mode": "0644",
        "mtime": 1485452789.0,
        "nlink": 1,
        "path": "/vagrant/provision/playbooks/roles/ansible/files/.ansible.cfg",
        "pw_name": "vagrant",
        "readable": true,
        "rgrp": true,
        "roth": true,
        "rusr": true,
        "size": 164,
        "uid": 1000,
        "wgrp": false,
        "woth": false,
        "writeable": true,
        "wusr": true,
        "xgrp": false,
        "xoth": false,
        "xusr": false
    }
}

TASK [ansible : copy .ansible.cfg to home directory] ***************************

ok: [controller] => {
    "changed": false,
    "checksum": "46acc076fda7e38fd7262fbc88f8ab4e1f52ddca",
    "dest": "/home/vagrant/.ansible.cfg",
    "diff": {
        "after": {
            "path": "/home/vagrant/.ansible.cfg"
        },
        "before": {
            "path": "/home/vagrant/.ansible.cfg"
        }
    },
    "gid": 1000,
    "group": "vagrant",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "backup": null,
            "content": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": "/home/vagrant/.ansible.cfg",
            "diff_peek": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "force": false,
            "group": "vagrant",
            "mode": 420,
            "original_basename": ".ansible.cfg",
            "owner": "vagrant",
            "path": "/home/vagrant/.ansible.cfg",
            "recurse": false,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": ".ansible.cfg",
            "state": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "mode": "0644",
    "owner": "vagrant",
    "path": "/home/vagrant/.ansible.cfg",
    "secontext": "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0",
    "size": 164,
    "state": "file",
    "uid": 1000
}

TASK [ansible : stat ansible inventory file] ***********************************

ok: [controller] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
            "follow": false,
            "get_checksum": true,
            "get_md5": true,
            "mime": false,
            "path": null
        },
        "module_name": "stat"
    },
    "stat": {
        "exists": false
    }
}

TASK [ansible : copy .inventory to home directory] *****************************

task path: /Users/alessandro/Go/src/github.com/alesr/neo4go/provision/playbooks/roles/ansible/tasks/main.yml:31
skipping: [controller] => {
    "changed": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed",
    "skipped": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inventory_file` is a [magic variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) and is set by Ansible during playbook run overwriting any values you try to assign.

In your inventory `stat` task you may notice: `invocation.module_args.path: null`.

Rename your `inventory_file` variable to `my_inventory_file` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check this out.

Answer (score -1):

`copy` sees the file is already there and is saying there's no change, but is identical to your source and not making a change.

The debug output shows:

```
stat_ansible_config.stat.exists = True
stat_inventory.stat.exists = False
```

and that explains the behavior difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand what you meant. Can you please reformulate your answer?

Comment: In debug of the stat module calls, the json that is assigned to the register shows: 

           "exists": true, and "exists": false,

Comment: Yes, excetly I've notice that. But the file is not there in reality.

Comment: Before statting the file, do `command: ls -la /home/{{ user }}` and post that debug output.